# Pivot Charts in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, visualization, data-analysis, pivot-chart

I created multiples Pivot tables from  different external data sources. There are six pivot tables that reference the same information but from 6 different months. I am trying to create a Pivot chart with the information on those 6 pivot tables.
I tried multiple ways and still can't get the pivot chart done.
Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

I tried:

- Select the cell where you want to insert the PivotChart.
- Go to the "Insert" tab on the Excel ribbon and click on the "PivotChart" button in the "Charts" group.
- In the "Create PivotChart" dialog box, select the table or range of data that you want to use as the data source for the PivotChart.
- Choose the type of chart you want to create and click "OK".
- The PivotChart will be created and attached to the data source table or range.
- To add another table range to the PivotChart, click anywhere within the chart to select it.
- Go to the "PivotChart Tools" tab on the Excel ribbon and click on the "Analyze" tab.
- In the "Data" group, click on the "Change Data Source" button.
- In the "Change PivotChart Data Source" dialog box, click on the "Add" button.
- In the "Add Data Source" dialog box, select the cell range for the new table or range that you want to add.
- Click "OK" to close the "Add Data Source" dialog box.
- Repeat steps for each additional table or range that you want to add to the PivotChart.

When I "Change Data Source", a new Pivot Chart is created. That's not what I am looking for.
I am looking to have diferent columns referents to the data on the 6 pivot tables.